# Compile with static libraries

Tags: c++, eclipse, opencv, static-libraries, static-linking

I am trying to compile two C++ projects with static libraries, with Eclipse C++ running at ubuntu 14.04.2. I have already achieved my purpose with the first one by writting the following command from terminal:

> g++ -o example main.cpp -static

Now, if I write "ldd example", the answer I obtain is: "It is not a dynamical executable"

However, the second project is using OpenCV (v 2.4.9) libraries. So, the previous command does not works to create a statical executable. I have also tried others such as:

> g++ -o example main.cpp -static `pkg-config --static --libs opencv`
>
> g++ -o example main.cpp `pkg-config --static --libs opencv`

But the first does not work (error in libcalib3d.so), and the second one creates the executable but with a lot of libraries dependences. Can anyone help me? If other information is needed please let me know and I will edit the post. Thank you!

EDIT: 
Writting in terminal this: pkg-config --static --libs opencv

The output I obtain is the following:

> /usr/local/lib/libopencv_calib3d.so
>   /usr/local/lib/libopencv_contrib.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so
>   /usr/local/lib/libopencv_features2d.so
>   /usr/local/lib/libopencv_flann.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_gpu.so
>   /usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so
>   /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_legacy.so
>   /usr/local/lib/libopencv_ml.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_nonfree.so
>   /usr/local/lib/libopencv_objdetect.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_ocl.so
>   /usr/local/lib/libopencv_photo.so
>   /usr/local/lib/libopencv_stitching.so
>   /usr/local/lib/libopencv_superres.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_ts.a
>   /usr/local/lib/libopencv_video.so
>   /usr/local/lib/libopencv_videostab.so -lrt -lpthread -lm -ldl

EDIT 2:
The file opencv.pc contains the following lines

> prefix=/usr exec_prefix=${prefix}
>   libdir=${prefix}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
>   includedir_old=${prefix}/include/opencv
>   includedir_new=${prefix}/include
>
> Name: OpenCV Description: Open Source Computer Vision Library Version:
>   2.4.8 Libs: -L${libdir} ${exec_prefix}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_calib3d.so
>   -lopencv_calib3d ${exec_prefix}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_contrib.so
>   -lopencv_contrib ${exec_prefix}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_core.so -lopencv_core ${exec_prefix}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_features2d.so
>   -lopencv_features2d ${exec_prefix}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_flann.so -lopencv_flann
>   ${exec_prefix}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_gpu.so -lopencv_gpu
>   ${exec_prefix}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.so
>   -lopencv_highgui ${exec_prefix}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_imgproc.so
>   -lopencv_imgproc ${exec_prefix}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_legacy.so
>   -lopencv_legacy ${exec_prefix}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_ml.so -lopencv_ml ${exec_prefix}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_objdetect.so -lopencv_objdetect ${exec_prefix}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_ocl.so -lopencv_ocl
>   ${exec_prefix}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_photo.so -lopencv_photo
>   ${exec_prefix}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_stitching.so
>   -lopencv_stitching ${exec_prefix}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_superres.so
>   -lopencv_superres ${exec_prefix}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_ts.so -lopencv_ts ${exec_prefix}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_video.so -lopencv_video ${exec_prefix}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_videostab.so
>   -lopencv_videostab Cflags: -I${includedir_old} -I${includedir_new}

Comment: Does your system has a static version of opencv libs installed ? (I guess this is the problem). You will probably need to generate it on your own, from opencv sources.

Comment: Sincerely, I do not know, is there a way to know if they are installed? Or, how can I generate them? I am not familiar with this matters... Thank you for your answer

Comment: Check in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu that you have both .so and .a files for all the libs that you need. I think that the first command line that you had is the correct one, but the problem is that is does not find a static libcalib3d (libcalib3d.a).

Comment: Yes, you were very right! There are only the .so extensions... I am trying to generate the .a by redoing the cmake instruction for opencv but it does not work for me. Do you have any idea how to generate them? Thank you very much1

Comment: Before trying to compile OpenCV (which may be painful, it's a big package...), I'd try to reinstall it from the packages (I'm using Debian, and it has the .a libs), maybe updating the package opencv-dev from your favourite package manager (synaptics, aptitude....) will install the .a

Comment: You are right again. Now I have the .a files but the compilation commands I wrote in the question continue giving me the same errors

Comment: Argh, back to zero, can you send the output of "pkg-config --static --libs opencv" ? (I'll tell you if I see something in there...)

Comment: Maybe something is corrupted in your installation of opencv. Check the content of the file /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/opencv.pc

Comment: I editted the post to show you the output. It seems it looks for .so extensions instead of .a or something similar..

Comment: (anyway, it seems that pkgconfig for opencv does not know about the --static flag and always tries to link with the .so, you will probably need another command line, I'm investigating...)

Comment: Absolutely true. I did the second edit showing the opencv.pc content.

Comment: I think I got it: g++ -o example main.cpp -static -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_contrib  -lopencv_core -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_flann -lopencv_gpu -lopencv_highgui  -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_ml -lopencv_objdetect  -lopencv_ocl -lopencv_photo -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_superres -lopencv_ts -lopencv_video -lopencv_videostab

Comment: two notes: (1) there should be a mean of getting that with pkg-config but I don't know (2) there are probably tons of libs that you do not need in the command line, but normally if will not link the unused ones in the executable in the end.

Comment: I really like your compilation command, but unfortunately it does not work for me at all. I got a lot of errors in the static libraries now and in .cpp.o objects. Maybe I have to reinstall all OpenCV since the beginning because it seems all you told me would be enough to statically link the libraries. Thank you a lot!

Comment: Guys, this isn't a forum ...

Comment: I have reinstalled all the opencv staff but it doesnt work...